# Windows 10 Hdmi nightmare

Tags: windows-10, hdmi

I have a windows 10 64 bit machine with all available updates.  I have an evga nvidia 1080 gtx card with latest nvidia drivers.  I have an asrock z170 itx mb with latest bios.  I have PCI selected as my primary graphics card.  I have disabled the onboard graphics in the BIOs.

When the hdmi port from my vid card is connected to my monitor, there is signal during the BIOS boot process, then I see the windows icon and about 2 seconds of the loading spinny wheel, then the screen goes black and no signal.

If I boot into the BIOS, the hdmi output works fine so it's not a monitor, mb or graphics card issue.  It's something in Windows 10 that decides it doesn't like HDMI at some point during the boot process.  I have tried uninstalling and re-installing drivers.  No luck.

Everything I have read about this problem in online forums I have already tried without progress.  Does anyone have any other ideas as to what I can try?

**Edit 1**

Tried reverting to an earlier BIOS (v2.3) no luck.  Tried setting the PCI-E lane to Gen 3 instead of auto.  No luck.

Comment: Try to turn on your onboard graphics but keep your GTX 1080 as the primary display adapter. Or if you motherboard has an HDMI port, try that and keep your GTX 1080 as the primary display adapter. Attempt both again with your GTX 1080 disabled and your onboard graphics enabled if that doesn't work. What is the resolution of your monitor? If you are using a 1440p or 4K monitor, try a HDMI cable that has 1440p or 4K support. I don't know if this any part of my comment will answer your question though.

Comment: I have a 1920x1080 monitor.  I will try using the on board graphics card to see if that works.

Comment: Nope, enabling the onboard card made it so I could not see anything anywhere (during bios boot nor windows boot).  Although using dvi still worked via PCI card but it was some weird resolution.  I had to reset my BIOS to get things working again.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happen once with a semi-broken monitor - it could run the lower resolution of the BIOS/boot screen, but not the higher res Windows screen. Try a different monitor & hdmi cable.

Comment: Problem with this theory is I have a laptop outputing to this monitor over hdmi with the same cable with no issues.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is down voted. It may not be the right answer for the OP at the moment but some future users with similar problems may find it useful. The question is "does anyone have any other ideas as to what I can try?" and this is a reasonable answer.

Comment: It was not me who down voted it.  Seems like whoever did fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this was all an issue from my KVM.  I tested all components using my wifes latop, then I plugged her laptop and my PC into an HDMI kvm (brand new) and was getting this issue.

When I swapped the channels on the KVM (so my PC was on channel 2 and laptop channel 1, I reversed the two) now it seems to work.  So there must be something different between the two channels that Windows 10 doesn't like.